# MVC4 List and link to all files in a web directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, directoryinfo

I have a MVC4 site (www.testsite.com/test)
I also have a separate directory for storing downloadable files (www.testsite.com/downloads)

I have configured the downloads directory to be browsable in IIS.

How can I read the contents of the directory and generate a list of files in MVC?

I have read up on the `DirectoryInfo GetFiles()` method but It only works for local directories and the /Downloads directory is on a test server.

Comment: `"but It only works for local directories and the /Downloads directory is on a test server"` - If the folder isn't on the same server as the web application, where is it?  How does the web application have access to it?  If the web application can't see that folder then of course it can't get the list of files in that folder.  Additionally, if the directory is browsable, then why not just link to the directory?  IIS creates a list of files for you.

Comment: allow me to explain, in production the two will be on the same server, but my development enviroment doesn't have a copy of the directory. also I thought that it would be good to have this loose coupling via providing a URL for the directory. I just thought that there would be a simple way to enumertate the files at a specific URL in c#. I dont Use the default list because it is pretty UGLY, I am thinking on parsing it extracting the links from it, that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a `Web.config` value for the folder.  Something like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DownloadsDirectory" value="C:\path\to\folder" />
</appSettings>
```

For any given instance of the application (local development instance, test server instance, production server instance, etc.) you'd update that instance's `Web.config` to specify the folder relevant to that instance.  They don't all have to use the same folder, each can use whatever folder is appropriate.  So your development machine doesn't need to access the production server's folder, just point it to some directory on your computer.

Second, use that value when reading from the directory.  For example:

```
var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DownloadsDirectory"]);
```

Naturally you'll want to check in code if `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DownloadsDirectory"]` *has* a value before trying to use it, and raise an error that the configuration is invalid if there's no value.  You might even use `Directory.Exists()` with the value as another check, again raising a friendly error if it doesn't exist.

The main point is that if you want to get information on files in a directory, `Directory` or `DirectoryInfo` or lots of other objects in `System.IO` are pretty much what you'd use.